# Why isn't srcset choosing the smaller image closer to viewport size

Tags: html, image, src, srcset

```
<img src="/images/photo-236x61.png" srcset="/images/photo-170x44.png 170w, 
/images/photo-236x61.png 236w, 
/images/photo-300x72.png 300w, 
/images/photo-472x121.png 472w, 
/images/photo-600x154.png 600w, 
/images/photo-943x242.png 943w" 
sizes="(min-width: 1341px) 450px, 
(min-width: 1181px) 400px, 
(min-width: 961px) 350px, 
(min-width: 881px) 325px, 
(min-width: 801px) 300px, 
(min-width: 721px) 250px, 
(min-width: 561px) 220px, 
(min-width: 481px) 200px, 
(min-width: 401px) 170px, 
(min-width: 321px) 150px, 
(min-width: 160px) 130px, 
calc(100vw - 30px)" alt="My Photo">
```

I have the above image which as a fair number of different sizes based on how the designer wired things up.  However, I'm running into weird issues where srscset always wants to pick much larger images than it needs to.  For example, when the viewport is at 420px wide its picking the much larger 300px width image instead of the smaller ones that more closely match the srcset widths provided.  Not sure why the queries aren't causing it to pick the correct sizes in different scenarios.  Any one have any ideas how to know what the browser picks and why?

Comment: Could it be that the browser already has a larger size in cache so it does not load a smaller one?

Answer (score 1):

**srcset** defines the list of images and what size each image is (the image's real size). This directive allows the browser to choose between them.

**sizes** defines a set of media conditions (e.g. screen widths) and indicates what image size would be best to choose, when certain media conditions are true.

The order of sizes rule is important because the browser ignores everything after the first matching condition, so I think that the problem here should be the order.

When the viewport is at 420px wide, first **sizes** condition tells: "when the viewport width is 1341 pixels or more load the image referenced in the **srcset** list that most closely matches the chosen slot size (450px)".

The condition that is true is:

```
(min-width: 401px) 170px
```

The screen density is probably at least 2 (so 2 * 170px = 340px) so browser will choose **srcset** image: `/images/photo-300x72.png 300w` that match the **sizes** condition.

Here is a [useful article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) on how responsive images work.

Comment: In part that may have been it but after a bit more reading it would appear it is the pixel density that is triggering it to choose the larger image.  Small devices like mobile phones often have pixel densities of ratio 2 or even 3 in some cases.  This means while the pixel width is only 400px wide on the phone, its density is 2 so it goes to the 800px width image instead so that it can render the clearer image.  Seems if I want to force a smaller image beyond certain media queries im better off using the picture element instead.

Comment: yes, what you say is true, once the order is corrected, it happens exactly as you described it. Browser chose image that is closest to width * pixel density and resize it to width indicated in matched sizes rule.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct.  The first condition does not say "when the viewport width is 1341 pixels or less", it says "when the viewport width is 1341 pixels or MORE".  At 420px viewport width this is the condition that is true: `(min-width: 401px) 170px`.  The screen density is probably at least 2 (so 2 * 170px = 340px) so it's using the 300w image.